# OTP is not getting from firebase code is proper

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to get OTP from Firebase to my phone for verification purpose, i have done everything as the documentation says but at the end i am not getting OTP please help me, i know something is wrong with my code anyone can correct me ?
my app is connected and working with firebase here is my activity java code :

[still am getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77pSO.png)

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String phone_number;
FirebaseAuth auth;
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

        }
    };

    CardView card_view = findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    card_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText phonetextview = findViewById(R.id.phonetextview);
            phone_number = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phonetextview.getText().toString());

            send();

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phone_number,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}

private void send() {

    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phone_number,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
    }
}
```

here is the logcat

```
2019-03-08 15:29:36.095 22108-22108/com.example.meenvandi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.meenvandi, PID: 22108
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.meenvandi. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:219)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance(Unknown Source:5)
    at com.example.meenvandi.LoginActivity.send(LoginActivity.java:96)
    at com.example.meenvandi.LoginActivity.access$000(LoginActivity.java:28)
    at com.example.meenvandi.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:77)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6330)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25136)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6778)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)
```

2019-03-08 15:29:36.108 22108-22108/com.example.meenvandi I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22108 SIG: 9

[i am getting this error after creating class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we0Mk.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.meenvandi"
tools:ignore="ExtraText">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Otp"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>
```

Updated Codes

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String phone_number;
 FirebaseAuth auth;
 PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);




    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() 
 {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }

        }
    };


    CardView card_view = findViewById(R.id.cardView);

    card_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {




            EditText phonetextview = findViewById(R.id.phonetextview);
            phone_number = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phonetextview.getText().toString());

            send();



            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phone_number,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();



        }


    });

}

private void send() {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phone_number,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks


}

}
```

Applicationclass

```
package com.example.meenvandi;

import android.app.Application;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;

public class Applicationclass extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);//here we are intializing firebase
}
}
```

updated manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.meenvandi"
tools:ignore="ExtraText">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<application
    android:name="com.example.meenvandi.Applicationclass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Otp"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

gradle 1

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

 allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}

 task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

gradle 2

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 28
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.meenvandi"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
 }
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: try  @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: code is proper?

Comment: yes it looks proper.

Comment: then why it is happeining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `intialize firebase` before using it .For that create one `Application` class .i.e :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);//here we are intializing firebase
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<application
        android:name="yourPackage.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/route"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
 <!--your activity classes-->
  <activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            >
 </application>
```

Comment: see the screenshot from quiestion

Comment: it should extends `Application` not `LoginActivity` ,see my code properly !

Comment: i should create new java class with your code thats it right ? i am a newbie

Comment: android:name=".YourActivity" here what should i add ?  android:name=".LoginActivity" ?

Comment: Yes,all your `activity classes` which are there in your project.

Comment: loggin activity is already there , see my code is that proper?

Comment: You forget to add this `android:name="yourPackage.MyApplication"` in your `<application>` tag.

Comment: android:name="com.example.meenvandi.Applicationclass" is this correct?

Comment: post your `app/build.gradle` and `root-level build.gradle` also all your updated code.

Comment: please have a look

Comment: i am expecting a solution from you

Comment: In your app level gradle add ->  `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom

Comment: added same this is happening

Comment: In your root-level gradle change  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'` to this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'`

Comment: in both gradle should i change?  there are two 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' in two gradles

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not on emulator and then make sure you have added your valid SHA-1 key to the firebase console.

Try this to check what error you are getting

```
    @Override 
     public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) { 
           e.printStackTrace(); 
     }
```

Comment: there is one SHA-1 fingerprint in fire-base 52:4e:0c:e9:a0:7a:af:89:23:29:1f:74:31:06:95:2c:f5:99:e0:cb
SHA-1

Comment: i have added logcat